# Phantomjs javascript inheritance misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, inheritance, phantomjs

I have following files:

- run.js (to run whole script)
- animal.js (parent abstract class for cat)
- animal/cat.js (child class for animal, on which I want to invoke methods)

run.js

```
var cat = require('./animal/cat').create('Tom');
console.log( cat.petName );
console.log( cat.paws );
cat.voice();
```

animal.js

```
function animal(){
   this.paws = 4;
}

exports.create = function(){
    return new animal();
}
```

animal/cat.js

```
function cat( name ){
    this.petName = name
}

cat.voice = function(){
    console.log('myouu');
}

exports.create = function( name ){
    cat.prototype = require('../animal').create();
    return new cat( name );
}
```

When I console log the properties of cat class -- everything works just fine. Prompt prints:
Tom
4
Which means that cat yet inherits from animal.
But when it comes to calling the method, following error occurs:
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'cat.voice()')
run.js:4 in global code

I just can't comprehend what is the matter. Can anybody explain error?

Comment: Does this only occur in PhantomJS?

Comment: I use PhantomJS's module inheritance pattern through exports.create which is not usable in browser environment

Comment: @Helvdan: `exports.create` is not an inheritance pattern. PhantomJS inheritance is the same as the browser. `exports.create` and `require` together is the same as the browser's `<script src=...>` feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `voice` function is a method of the `cat()` constructor, not the `cat` object (returned by the constructor). In other languages this is called the class method or static method.

To create a method for the `cat` object you need to add it to the prototype:

```
cat.prototype.voice = function(){
    console.log('myouu');
}
```

But beware, in your cat create function you then overwrite the prototype. So doing this:

```
exports.create = function( name ){
    cat.prototype = require('../animal').create();
    return new cat( name );
}
```

will delete the voice method if defined like the example I show above. The correct way to do this is that you need to inherit before declaring additional methods:

```
cat.prototype = require('../animal').create();
cat.prototype.voice = function(){
    console.log('myouu');
}

exports.create = function( name ){
    return new cat( name );
}
```